# Best way to sort customerAddress in such a way that all primary address are at the top and others at the bottom

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am trying to sort the below list in such a way that primary address is at the top of the list followed by other address (p.getIsPrimary is a Boolean value and can be null). Is there any other way other than below?

````
List<CustomerAddress> primaryAddress = customerAddresses.stream()
                                       .filter(p->Boolean.TRUE.equals(p.getIsPrimary()))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<CustomerAddress> secondaryAddress = customerAddresses.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

secondaryAddress.removeAll(primaryAddress);
primaryAddress.addAll(secondaryAddress);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **sort** primary addresses first, call `sort()` with a `Comparator` that orders primary addresses before non-primary addresses, e.g.

```java
customerAddresses.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(
        a -> a.getIsPrimary() != null && a.getIsPrimary() ? 0 : 1));
```

The code sorts by an `int` value, a kind of "sort order" value, where 0 = primary and 1 = non-primary.

Comment: Adding another question to add to the above. How can we do alphabetical order sort and then put primary on top?

Comment: @PraveenKadri By looking at the *documentation* of `Comparator` and using the `thenComparing()` method to apply a secondary sort order. Or you could do a web search for e.g. [`java sort multiple fields`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+sort+multiple+fields) to learn how.

Comment: i tried looking at the thenComparing() and when i  use Collections.sort(customerEmailAddresses,Comparator.comparingInt(
                    a -> a.getIsPrimary() != null && a.getIsPrimary() ? 0 : 1)
            .thenComparing(CustomerEmailAddress::getEmailAddress));  getIsPrimary() is giving object not found compilation. I guess i am missing something basic

Comment: The inference engine gets confused, so you need to help it, by using either `Comparator.<CustomerEmailAddress>comparingInt( a ->` or `Comparator.comparingInt( (CustomerEmailAddress a) ->`

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a partitioning: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

```
Map<Boolean, List<CustomerAddress>> primarySecondary =
  customerAddresses.stream()
                   .collect(partitioningBy(p -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(p.getIsPrimary()))
;
```

This would give you:

- `primarySecondary.get(true)` : all primaries.
- `primarySecondary.get(false)` : all secondaries.